# Div inside div adjust to screen width and keep ratio of image and also adjust width of other div

Tags: css

I’m making my site resonsive and I’m struggeling with a div with a image inside of it, I want to keep the aspect ratio of the picture and then the picture (of course) gets less high. How to make the div col_1 adjust to that hight and als adjust col_2 in width and hight? The div row has to adjust its hight to keep everything closed.

```
<div class=”row”>
    <div class=”col_1”>
         <img src=”some”>
    </div>
    <div class=”col_2”>
       Text<br>
       Text<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code? Put up the code.

Comment: I did,haha, but how to comment out the HTML. Its now going up in the page...

Comment: put your code, select the code then [ctrl+k]

Comment: Thanks, that did the job

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is used in the snippet below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/love_wallpaper_vector_3d_wallpaper_261.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        Text
        <br>Text
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. Bootstrap does it. I don't work with skeleton so I don't know if it has something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to adjust the img height and width to that of the parent element?

If yes use the bootstrap class="img-responsive" on your img tag.

```
<img src="someImage" class="img-responsive">
```

The .img-responsive class applies max-width: 100%, height: auto, and display:block to the image.
[See more](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp)